# glovePIE: How to bind mouse middle button to wiimote.nunchucks.C and Z

Tags: wiimote

How do I write code in glovePIE to basically input mouse.middlebutton when I press C and Z on Wii Nunchuks?

I've been trying out stuff like:
`Wiimote.Nunchuk.C + Wiimote.Nunchuk.Z = MiddleButton`
but to no avail. Tried out other possibilities but haven't found anything that works.